# Targeting a tags which wrap img's for fancybox using jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I can't seem to work out why this simple `.parent()` is not working.

Currently inside my `div.entry` I have text links and image links.

The image links always wrap img's

And the hyperlinks are just text.

If I add this script, then all my a tags inside `div.entry` launch fancy box...

```
$(".entry a").fancybox();
```

So to target just the img hyperlinks (which are links to my fullsize image), I tried all of these...

```
$(".entry a img").parent('a').fancybox();

$(".entry a img").parent().fancybox();

$(".entry a img").closest('a').fancybox();
```

But none of these seem to work??

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do that would be:

```
$('.entry a:has(img)');
```

but your way of doing it should also work.

What do you get if you try `console.log( $(".entry a img") )`?

Comment: Hi Joseph, the a:has(img) works thank you. Do you mean write... `console.log ( $(".entry a img").parent().fancybox(); )` or just this in it's place... `console.log( $(".entry a img") )` ? Console is currently clean of warning/errors